How to Filter and Handle Input Character Removal
I'm working on a application where I need to filter tasks based on their title or description. The filter works well when characters are added to the input, but it fails when characters are removed. For example, if I type "create" and then delete the "reate", the filter does not update correctly.
When I start typing in the input field, the filtering works as expected. However, if I backspace to remove characters from the query, the list of tasks does not update properly.
Are there any best practices when implementing this type of filtering?
Demo Stackblitz
main.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
  <input type="text" name="task-filter" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchValue">
  @for (task of tasks ;track task.id) {
        <div class="task">
          <div>{{task.title}}</div>
          <div>{{task.description}}</div>
        </div>
      }
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  tasks!: Task[];
  tasksSubscription!: Subscription;
  searchValue: string = '';

  constructor(public taskService: TaskService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.tasksSubscription = this.taskService.tasks$.subscribe((tasks) => {
      this.tasks = tasks;
    });
  }

  public onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    this.taskService.filterTasks(this.searchValue);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.tasksSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

task-service.ts
export class TaskService {
  private _tasks$: BehaviorSubject<Task[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Task[]>([]);
  constructor() {
    this.fetchTasks();
  }

  public fetchTasks() {
    const tasks: Task[] = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Create Project Plan',
        description:
          'Develop a detailed project plan for the new software project.',
        category: 'Management',
        status: 'In Progress',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Conduct Code Review',
        description:
          'Perform a code review for the recently implemented feature.',
        category: 'Development',
        status: 'Pending',
      },
    ];
    this._tasks$.next(tasks);
  }

  public get tasks$(): Observable<Task[]> {
    return this._tasks$.asObservable() as Observable<Task[]>;
  }

  public get tasks(): Task[] {
    return this._tasks$.getValue() as Task[];
  }

  public filterTasks(searchText: string): void {
    if (!searchText) {
      this._tasks$.next(this.tasks);
    }

    searchText = searchText.toLowerCase();

    const filteredTasks = this.tasks.filter(
      (task) =>
        task.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText) ||
        task.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
    );

    this._tasks$.next(filteredTasks);
  }
}


From the getter as below:
public get tasks(): Task[] {
  return this._tasks$.getValue() as Task[];
}

You are getting the value from the observable. While in your filterTasks, you have updated the task$ observable value during filtering. Thus, you can't get back the original data for the tasks.
Instead, you may look to store the tasks data in the tasks variable and not update it.
And remove the tasks getter.
export class TaskService {
  private _tasks$: BehaviorSubject<Task[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Task[]>([]);
  tasks: Task[] = [];
  constructor() {
    this.fetchTasks();
  }

  public fetchTasks() {
    this.tasks = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Create Project Plan',
        description:
          'Develop a detailed project plan for the new software project.',
        category: 'Management',
        status: 'In Progress',
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Conduct Code Review',
        description:
          'Perform a code review for the recently implemented feature.',
        category: 'Development',
        status: 'Pending',
      },
    ];
    this._tasks$.next(this.tasks);
  }

  ...
}

Demo @ StackBlitz

Did you share the wrong stackblitz demo? Your example do not work.

Hi, sorry about that, I updated the link in the answer. Thanks.

The problem is that you are using the last emission of the BehaviorSubject as your source of tasks.  However, you are also pushing your filtered list through the same subject.  Therefore, you end up using the filtered list as your source array to filter from.
Best practices:

do not return an observable from a getter
do not subscribe in your services; expose observables that consumers can subscribe to.
leverage rxjs operators to design an observable that emits exactly the data you are interested in
leverage Angular's async pipe when possible to alleviate the need to manage subscriptions in your component


Your code is much more complicated than necessary, so let's simplify:
In the service, let's start by declaring two observables, one to represent the fetched tasks, and one to represent the current search term, since those are the two pieces of information we need in order to build the filtered list. The search term will actually be a BehaviorSubject so we can push values through. The second will be the result of calling your fetchTasks() method (which we will assume will return Observable<Task[]>).
  // service

  private searchText$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  private allTasks$ = this.fetchTasks();

  public setSearchText(text: string) {
    this.searchText$.next(text);
  }

  private fetchTasks(): Observable<Task[]> {
    // ...
  }

Now, lets leverage the rxjs function combineLatest to build an observable that emits exactly the data we are interested in, the filtered list!
combineLatest takes an array of source observables and will emit their latest values whenever either of them emit (although the first emission will not occur until each has emitted at least one value).
This is exactly the behavior you want: emit the updated value whenever any source observable emits.
  public tasks$ = combineLatest([this.allTasks$, this.searchText$]).pipe(
    map(([tasks, searchText]) => tasks.filter(
      (task) => task.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
             || task.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchText.toLowerCase())
    ))
  );

Above tasks$ is declared to be an observable that will emit the filtered list whenever allTasks$ or searchText$ emits. Probably allTasks$ will only ever emit one value, and that is fine.  But, as searchText$ emits new values, the new filtered list is calculated using the full list of tasks and the newest search term value.
Notice we have not subscribed yet.  The service simply exposes a tasks$ observable that consumers can subscribe to and a setSearchText() method that can be used to "set" the search text within the service, which causes the tasks$ observable to emit the updated value.
Now, in your component, rather than:

subscribing to the service observable
storing the emission to a local variable
managing unsubscribing when the component is destroyed

You can simply bind the template directly the the task$ observable exposed by the service by using the async pipe:
  <input type="text" (keyup)="onKeyUp($event)">

  @for (task of service.tasks$ | async; track task.id) {
    <div class="task">
      <div>{{task.title}}</div>
      <div>{{task.description}}</div>
    </div>
  }

This makes your component code much simpler:
export class App {
  constructor(public service: TaskService) {}

  public onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent): void {
    const searchValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value ?? '';
    this.service.setSearchText(searchValue);
  }
}

There's hardly anything left!  No ngOnInit, no .subscribe(), no Subject, no ngOnDestroy no local variables to store state.
Here is a working StackBlitz

If the filtered list is only a concern of one component, it probably makes sense to move the filtering logic out of the service and into the component.  I'd probably do something like this.
